# How to write a loop to display multiples of primes in Java?

Tags: java, loops

My assignment reads:

Write a program that finds all of the prime numbers between one and some number that you allow the user to input.

- Find the prime numbers between 0 and the number the user inputs.
- Print these prime numbers, one per line.
- After each prime number, add a colon and then print out all the non-prime numbers that were eliminated.

Basically, these non-prime numbers are the multiples of the primes.

**For example**, the output will look like this:

```
2: 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18... 
3: 9 15 21 27
```

I did prime numbers. I can not figure out how to calculate and display multiples? Help, please!

```
package assignment4;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment4 {   /**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
   final int START = 1;
   System.out.print("Enter the end number number : ");
   int end = s.nextInt();
     System.out.println("List of prime numbers between " + START + " and "
     + end);
       for (int i = START; i <= end; i++) {
       if (isPrime(i)) {
           System.out.println(i + ":");
       }
   }
 }

   public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
   if (n <= 1) {
       return false;
   }
   for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
       if (n % i == 0) {
           return false;
       }
   }
   return true;}

 }
```

Comment: you just need to create an array and insert the prime numbers inside of it...

Comment: Some hints: (1) The third expression of a `for` doesn't have to be of the form `x++`.  You can have a `for` loop that looks like `for (int j = 2 * i; j <= end; j += i)`, which adds `i` to the index every time.  (2) It looks like you're only allowed to print each multiple once (you print 6 on the line beginning with 2, so you can't print it on the "3" line).  There are a couple good ways to keep track of numbers you've already printed: `Set` and an array of boolean.

Comment: From the wording of the question, particularly the phrase "non-prime numbers that were eliminated", I think your teacher would like you to use the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm for finding the prime numbers.  Wikipedia page is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 0):

Displaying multiples would be easy if you were sieving using sieve of Erathrosthenes. You create an array of numbers from 2 to n. start with 2, mark non-prime all its multiples: 2 4 6... print them. Choose next prime number (i.e. the number which was not marked unprime) i.e. 3, mark non-prime all its multiples (which haven't been already): 9 15 ... and so on.

Simplest Solution:

```
    boolean[] x = new boolean[N];// x[i] is true when i is not prime
    for(int i=2;i<N;i++){
        if(!x[i]){
            System.out.print(i+" : ");
            for(int j=i*i;j<N;j+=i){
                if(!x[j])
                System.out.print(j+" ");
                x[j]=true;
            }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not quite good enough. Look at the expected output for "3": it doesn't have 12, but your algorithm would print it.  I don't think that doing someone's homework for them is a good idea in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to have print the multiples until the `end` number. You could nest a while loop that multiplies the prime number as follows:

```
for (int i = START; i <= end; i++) {
   if (isPrime(i)) {
       System.out.print(i + ": "); //Changed to print so that the multiples are on the same line
       int multiple = i * 2;
       while (multiple <= end) {
           multiple += i;
           System.out.print(multiple + ", ");
       }
       System.out.println("");
   }
}
```

Comment: Not quite good enough.  Look at the expected output for "3":  it doesn't have 6 or 12.

Comment: What `end` did you use? I specified that the loop should continue printing until it reached the `end`, but you can specify some other value if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below answer for your requirement,

```
  package assignment4; 

  import java.util.*;
  import java.lang.*;
  import java.io.*;


  public class Assignment4
  {
          public static List<Integer> primeNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        public static String strOtherData[];

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
      {
        final int START = 1;
        System.out.print("Enter the end number number : ");
        int end = s.nextInt();

        System.out.println("List of prime numbers between " + START + " and "  + end);

         for (int i = START; i <= end; i++) {
              if (isPrime(i)) {
                    primeNumbers.add(i);
                }
            }

          strOtherData = new String[primeNumbers.size()];

            for (int i = START; i <= end; i++) {
                isMultiple(i);
            }

          int tempCount = 0;
            for(Integer currentNumber : primeNumbers)
          {
                System.out.print(currentNumber + ": \t");

            if(strOtherData.length > tempCount)
                {
                System.out.print(strOtherData[tempCount] + "\n\n");
              }

                tempCount++;
          }
      }

      public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
          if (n <= 1) {
                  return false;
          }
          for (int i = 2; i <= n/2; i++) 
          {
              if (n % i == 0)
                {
                 return false;
              }
            }
          return true;
     }

     public static void isMultiple(int n)
     {
            if (n <= 1) {
                    return;
            }

          if(isPrime(n))
               return;

            int count = 0;
          for(Integer currentInt : primeNumbers)
            {
                if(strOtherData[count] != null)
                {
                   strOtherData[count] += "," + n;
                }
                else
                {
                    strOtherData[count] = "" + n;
                }
              count++;
          }
     }
  }
```